# include specific rows based on certain condition in one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, hierarchy

| emp_id | emp | level | manager_id | manager_1 | manager_2 | manager_3 | leader |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 1 | 500 | sam | chuck | matt | yes |
| 200 | B | 2 | 600 | sam | chuck | joe | no |
| 300 | C | 2 | 700 | sam | chuck | amy | no |
| 400 | D | 3 | 800 | sam | chuck | brian | yes |

I have a table with employees and their respective managers in column 'emp' and 'manager' respectively. I want to include the names in the manager column only if the leader column for the respective value in the leader column is yes and if the leader column has a 'no' value for a manager then it should be marked as NULL

This is the expected result

| emp_id | emp | level | manager_id | manager_1 | manager_2 | manager_3 | leader |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 1 | 500 | sam | chuck | matt | yes |
| 200 | B | 2 | 600 | sam | chuck | NULL | no |
| 300 | C | 2 | 700 | sam | chuck | NULL | no |
| 400 | D | 3 | 800 | sam | chuck | brian | yes |

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE WHEN or IIF:

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN leader = 'yes' THEN manager ELSE NULL END AS manager
FROM [my_table]

SELECT *
      ,IIF(leader = 'yes', manager, NULL) AS manager
FROM [my_table]
```

Comment: I have updated my question. there are few more conditions/columns in the original data.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to include the names in the manager column only if the leader
> column for the respective value in the leader column is yes and if the
> leader column has a 'no' value for a manager then it should be marked
> as NULL

This can be done with simple case statement as :

```
SELECT emp_id, emp, level, manager_id,
  CASE WHEN leader = 'yes' THEN manager ELSE NULL END AS manager,
  leader
FROM employees;
```

This shall give you the expected output :

| emp_id | emp | level | manager_id | manager | leader |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 1 | 500 | sam | yes |
| 200 | B | 2 | 600 | NULL | no |
| 300 | C | 2 | 700 | NULL | no |
| 400 | D | 3 | 800 | nate | yes |

Edit :

Based on your updated question :

You can modify the query as below :

```
SELECT 
  emp_id, emp, level, manager_id, manager_1, manager_2, 
  CASE WHEN leader = 'yes' THEN manager_3 ELSE NULL END AS manager_3, 
  leader 
FROM 
  employees;
```

This shall give you the expected output : [as in this SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f06f325/26)

| emp_id | emp | level | manager_id | manager_1 | manager_2 | manager_3 | leader |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 1 | 500 | sam | chuck | matt | yes |
| 200 | B | 2 | 600 | sam | chuck | NULL | no |
| 300 | C | 2 | 700 | sam | chuck | NULL | no |
| 400 | D | 3 | 800 | sam | chuck | brian | yes |

Comment: I have updated my question. there are few more conditions/columns in the original data.

Comment: @User277883: I have updated the answer. Can you check it ?

Comment: no, this is not the expected answer. Following your code, resets all the rows as NULL. I want only manager_3 to be NULL when the people_leader is 'No' and retain manager_1 and manaher_2 as is.

Comment: If you see the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0decc/1; It matches your output.

`Following your code, resets all the rows as NULL. I want only manager_3 to be NULL when the people_leader is 'No' and retain manager_1 and manaher_2 as is`

Can I update in your question as Expected Output ?

Comment: manager_1 and manager_2 for employees B and C should not be NULL.

Comment: Well, You have updated the `Expected Output` now; I will update the answer in a while

Comment: @User277883 : I have updated output based on new requirement along with SQLFIDDLE.
It gives the expected output :)

Comment: where do i find the latest SQLFIDDLE?

Comment: It's in the post. Replaced with old one <http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f06f325/26>